# Как установить Style в коде?

Tags: java, android, android-button

Я создал новый style для кнопок:

```
<style name="ThemesNumsOne" parent="android:Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_theme_two</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorThemeOneTextNums</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">36sp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_light</item>
</style>
```

и унаследовал класс Button в java коде:

```
public class CalcButton extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton {

    public CalcButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setup(context);

    }

    public CalcButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setup(context);

    }

    public CalcButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setup(context);

    }

    private void setup(Context context) {
    }
}
```

ну вот, я хотел установить style в java коде, а не в xml макете.
но я не знаю как установить style в коде, если знаете подскажите пж...

---

```
public class CalcButton extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton {

    public CalcButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setup(context);

    }

    public CalcButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setup(context);

    }

    public CalcButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setup(context);

    }

    private void setup(Context context) {
    }

}
```

@Andrew Goroshko 
вот код унаследованы от Button. Там внизу есть метод setup и в этом методе я хочу установить style. 
Вопрос: как реализовать этого?

Answer (score 1):

Вот к примеру есть способ:

```
LinearLayout button = new LinearLayout(context, null, android.R.style.ButtonBar);
```

[ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422220/android-how-to-programmatically-set-the-button-style-in-a-linearlayout) на первоисточник. Или вот:

```
Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
bt.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.bt_style);
```

вот [ссылка](http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/tips/Android-style-button-programmatically.htm) на первоисточник. Вот еще есть подобный [ответ](https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/1ec3f9). Надеюсь один из предложенных вариантов окажется решением вашей проблемы. Если возникнут сложность с радостью поможем. Удачи :)

Comment: большое спасибо, и еще я хотел спросить. у меня там в коде есть метод setup и я хотел в этом методе написать или установит style , ну как то setStyle, знаю что такого метода нету. ну вот как этого реализовать?

Comment: не очень понятно если честно, дополните ответ пожалуйста...

Comment: дополните ответ пожалуйста или лучше создайте новый, потому что здесь не приветствуется создание вопроса состоящего из нескольких вопросов, если вас удовлетворил данный ответ пожалуйста отметьте его как принятый и сбросьте в комменты ссылку на новый вопрос, либо отредактируйте свой текущий вопрос

Comment: хорошо щас заново кину запрос